# how to select from enum field in spring

Tags: sql, spring

In my domain folder, I have the class `Produit`:

```
public class Produit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nom", nullable = false)
    private String nom;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "prix", nullable = false)
    private Float prix;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "source", nullable = false)
    private String source;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "categorie", nullable = false)
    private Categorie categorie;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "available", nullable = false)
    private Boolean available;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "promo", nullable = false)
    private Boolean promo;

    @Column(name = "prix_promo")
    private Float prixPromo;
}
```

I'm trying to select all the entities with a specific `categorie` using the function in the repository:

```
 @Query("Select p from Produit p where p.categorie = :x")
 List<Produit> findByCategorie(@Param("x") String categorie);
```

The `enum Category` contains:

```
public enum Categorie {
    Bio, Alimentation, Vetement
}
```

In the `ProduitResourse`, I've configured the `@GetMapping`:

```
@GetMapping("/produits/categorie/{categorie}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Produit>> getByCategorie(@PathVariable("categorie") String categorie) {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Produits for a specific category");
    List<Produit> page = produitRepository.findByCategorie(categorie);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(page);
}
```

But the server's response returns an `IllegalAgrument` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
@Query("Select p from Produit p where p.categorie = :x")
List<Produit> findByCategorie(@Param("x") Categorie categorie);
```

Hibernate is smart enough to understand that `categorie` is an Enum, and parses its value to correspond the value on the database.